# How to test slope parameter for simple regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I am learning R and how to do regressions in a biological context, so please forgive me.

I am stumped on how to test if a slope parameter is less than a certain number at the alpha = 0.05 level. These are my two correlation(?) coefficients:

> reg.fit <- lm(gro3 ~ gro2) # fit linear model
> reg.fit
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = gro3 ~ gro2)
>
> Coefficients:
>
> (Intercept),         gro2
> -0.8426,       0.3582

I *think* I should use a t-test to test these somehow. But I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. If you need help with statistical analysis, then you would be better off asking on the site dedicated to statistics: [stats.se].

Comment: The function `linearHypothesis` in the package AER may provide what you are looking for.